# Monitor settings get overriden

Tags: display, hdmi

Recently I noticed that when I start Doom Eternal, it somehow overrides a number of my monitor settings such as brightness, contrast, color profile, etc. The settings are different from mine, and they are greyed out in the monitor settings menu.
And I wonder, what technology can possibly do that? Drivers? Something in the HDMI protocols? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the search term you are looking for is: DDC/CI

**Display Data Channel (DDC) / Command Interface (CI)**

It's a protocol some monitors support to allow the computer to control the settings of the monitor - typically used in laptops. On external monitors there may be an option in the menus somewhere to allow you to turn it on and off - so that the computer can't control the brightness.

I suspect there is a second effect happening - in multiplayer gaming some players are using graphics card filters to increase brightness, reduce blur etc - in order to gain a competitive advantage. Nvidia allows game developer to turn off all all such filters when their game is running.

This is a guess, but I suspect you are seeing an interaction between these two systems - that the game is turning off GFX filters and as a result any brightness settings from the game are being applied through DCC/CI to the monitor.